# What does "carry a quadratic into a reduced one" mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, terminology

I was reading A. Adrian Albert's *Modern Higher Algebra* (1938). On p.30, there is such an exercise (emphasis mine):

> Let $\mathfrak F$ be a field of characteristic $2$ and $x^2+ax+b=0$ be a quadratic equation with coefficients $a\ne0$ and $b$ in $\mathfrak F$. Show that a linear transformation $x=cy+d$ with coefficients in $\mathfrak F$ **cannot carry our quadratic into a reduced quadratic** in $y$. But this can be done when $\mathfrak F$ does not have characteristic two.

What does the phrase in bold mean?

Comment: It probably means a quadratic with no linear term.

Comment: @rogerl Oh, I see. So, he probably meant that it is impossible to write $x^2+ax+b$ as $py^2+q$???

Comment: After such a transformation, yes.

Comment: @rogerl Thanks. If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely means that a linear transformation cannot produce a quadratic with no linear term over a field of characteristic $2$, but that it can if the field has a different characteristic.